# overpass-turbo Export CSV of all adresses

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

```
    [out:json][timeout:25];
(
node["addr:housenumber"="44"]({{bbox}});
way["addr:housenumber"="44"]({{bbox}});
relation["addr:housenumber"="44"]({{bbox}});
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

I would like to display all addresses from the following query in a list.

Say street, postal code and city,

How can I do this the easiest way?

I can't figure it out from the help.

Comment: howdy  - thanks - and how can i export the datadump!?

Answer (score 2):

In overpass-turbo, you can use something [like this](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1niV) that creates a CSV:

```
[out:csv('addr:city','addr:housenumber','addr:postcode','addr:state','addr:street',building;true;',')]
[timeout:25];
(
   nwr["addr:housenumber"="44"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
```

Ref: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL

Comment: howdy  - thanks - and how can i export the datadump!?